# PHPUnit - how to test sibling method calls?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

Given this code:

```
public function someMethod($conditions)
{
    if(<expression>) {
        $this->methodA();
    } else {
        $this->methodB();
    }
}
```

both `methodA()` and `methodB()` produce indirect output, and are each covered by their own units tests. I just want to test that `someMethod()` calls the appropriate sibling based on various conditions.

However, I don't know how to mock the object to test it.

This is what I tried:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('\My\Class')
             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
             ->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('methodA');

$mock->someMethod(['some' => 'condition']);
```

But it throws this error

Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

I know for a fact it's not a condition problem, as I took out the logic just to see if a straight method call would pass the test, but it doesn't. So I think Im just not mocking the object properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was just missing the `setMethods(['methodA'])` call in my mock.